# Restrict Alt+Tab to the current workspace in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab, window-switching

Is there a way to tweak <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Gnome 3 so it will iterate windows only in the current workspace?

I'm using Debian wheezy.

Comment: Which desktop environment (GNOME, KDE, XFCE, etc.)?

Comment: This is like asking "How do I activate cheat code in a game?" without specifying the game.

Comment: You are right :P , sorry for the omission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an extension for GNOME Shell which enables this behaviour: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/310/alt-tab-workspace/

Comment: This is no longer necessary given that there's now a settings that's configurable.  See the other answer.

Answer (score 35):

This command also does the trick:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only true
```

Comment: +1 in fact, changing this setting is exactly what the extension does.

Comment: @GabrielF correct. I don't remember why I left that out actually...