# Gnome shell - alt-tab prioritize current workspace

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, alt-tab

Is there a way to tweak the alt-tab behaviour in Gnome Shell to prioritize the current workspace?  Currently, alt-tab prioritizes windows used most recently, instead of windows in the current workspace.

I know how to [restrict alt-tab to the current workspace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171964/restrict-alttab-to-the-current-workspace-in-gnome-3), but I'm looking to prioritize the current workspace, not make it exclusive.  I found that the [Coverflow extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/97/coverflow-alt-tab/) does what I want - it has an option "All workspaces, current first" - but this extension removes the default application grouping behaviour, and does not offer an option to restore it.

There is an identical question [here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=295799) and [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=162000), so not optimistic about finding a solution, but figured I'd ask just in case.  This used to be the default behaviour on Gnome Shell 3.4, so kinda surprised that there isn't a way to do that any more.

Answer (score 1):

There is a gnome shell extension which seems to do this. It is called "Alt-Tab Current Workspace First", and can be downloaded/installed from https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1296/alt-tab-current-workspace-first/. (However I have not tested it and I do not know whether this extension falls back to the ungrouped alt-tab from the "AlternateTab" extension)

Comment: This one's neat. It's a compromise between what Coverflow does and what Gnome Shell used to do: It splits out the current workspace, while keeping application grouping on the remaining workspaces. I'm going to try it for a while to see if that's good enough. Thanks for the good suggestion!

Comment: Note: Moved to [App-Switcher Current Workspace First](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1329/app-switcher-current-workspace-first/).